# CGRectApplyAffineTransform Incorrect Result?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, geometry, core-graphics

I have a bit of code that is trying to figure out the correct bounding box for a rectangle that is being rotated -5 degrees:

```
CGRect rectangleToRotate = CGRectMake(0,0,104.949, 131.017);
CGAffineTransform rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI * -5) / 180);
CGRectApplyAffineTransform (rectangleToRotate, rotateTransform);
```

The result that is produced is a rectangle with size: `{115.968, 139.664}` which, for some reason is too huge and doesn't tightly encompass the rectangle. Yet when I go take this same scenario in Adobe Illustrator, the bounding box is: `{104.659, 132.143}` which is correct.

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: The illustrator Size can't be right, as a rotated rect will always be bigger than the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are doing something wrong in illustrator. How should the bounding box be smaller (104.9 to 104.6) AFTER a 5 degree rotation.. thats just wrong.

The CGRect results are quite right. I tested it in Photoshop.
A 105x131px rect will result in a 117x141px bounding box after a -5 degree rotation.